# What happens if I don't sell my share when my company is acquired

Tags: shares, corporate-acquisition

[Scientific gaming is to acquire bally](http://www.bloomberg.com/news/2014-08-01/scientific-games-buys-bally-technologies-for-5-1-billion.html) and will will pay $83.30 in cash per Bally common share. The shares are currently trading at around $78 from previous days close of around $60. I am not in immediate need of money, so I am just holding on to my **Bally** shares and not selling them yet. Am I correct in assuming that if I don't sell my shares, I will be paid $83.3 when the deal is closed. If so will the shares be automatically encashed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you're correct and yes they will. Note that it will be considered as "sale" with gains being taxable income to you.

Comment: Good way to save on commission too?

Comment: @MarkMonforti Actually, a commission for such a transaction may be higher than for a regular sale.